# JSON library problems using both Facebook API and Google Places API in the same app

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, facebook-graph-api, google-places-api

I'm encountering a problem with the JSON library using both Facebook API and Google Places API in the same app. I've tried them both independently and they work fine. The problem is though that I now have 2 sets of some of the JSON files (when using both Google and FB API).

I've tried removing one set but this only brings about more errors.

The SBJSON.h from the Facebook API is different than the SBJson.h from the Google Places API. I'm not sure how to work around this. any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: I had some problems like this, wasn't google places though. I just kept the FB one, it gave some warnings but worked fine. Did u try keeping the FB version only?

Comment: I just did that. How would I fix this error (no visible @interface for 'SBJsonParser' declares the selector 'objectWithString:error' in the Google Places connectionDidFinishLoading: method -  NSDictionary *parsedJSON    = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&jsonError];     thanks :)

Comment: I have an 'Interface method not found' warning. But the funny part is that it still finds it on runtime and parses my JSON. Does it crash for you?

Comment: Please write out the error message as part of the question.  There's no way a search engine is going to be able to create search terms as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- A. Custom prefix one of the 2 sbJson libraries and accordingly adjust the SDK (I wouldn't recommend this as it is a lot of work)
- B. Use one of the 2 libraries and fix the errors in the FB or Google SDK

The differences usually are minor and a few changes will do the trick...

Comment: thanks! I went with solution B. The only error I have now is: 'no visible @interface for 'SBJsonParser' declares the selector 'objectWithString:error' in the Google Places connectionDidFinishLoading: method - NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&jsonError]; any idea how I would fix this one? thanks again

Comment: Which SbJson library was newer? You should keep the newer. From what I see probably the Google SBJson SDK was newer

Comment: Yes, the Google is newer. I tried removing just the FB JSON files and encountered many more errors. The contents of the SBJON.h for FB and the SBJson.h for Google are different. Is it possible to keep both and somehow force FB just to use it's own JSON files and totally ignore Google's?

Comment: Which would entail going through all the FB JSON files and adding a prefix 'FBJSON.h" and so on. Does refactoring with Xcode handle that?

Comment: Renaming the library will not work. You'll need to custom prefix all shared methods. I would not recommend this it is a lot of work. Let me install FB SDK and Google Places SDK and see the conflict. Btw, I don't see an SDK for Google Places. What are you using ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10232/discussion-between-hanumandev-and-lefteris)

Comment: Solution B is the right answer Actually, solution C (download the current version of SBJSON and use that instead of either of these) would be even better.  The error in the first comment is caused by using the wrong SBJSON